# Golang GMAIL API 400: Invalid label:

Tags: go, gmail-api

Using **Gmail API** to read my mailbox. The message reading process is working as expected but I want to **change the label** of reading messages just for acknowledgment purposes so that I can have track of the reading messages list in my Gmail inbox only. Tried given two methods to change the label but non of them worked for me. Need suggestion on the same

**Methods:**

1. Codebase is written in Golang (as a backend)
2. Tried with Google API Explorer

(**METHOD 1**) -

*Go sample code:*

```
    gmsg: = gmail.ModifyMessageRequest {
        RemoveLabelIds: [] string {
            "INBOX". //system defined label
        },
        AddLabelIds: [] string {
            "INBOXING" //my custom label. created through Gmail
        },
    }
    
    _, errDelete: = gService.Users.Messages.Modify("me", messageid, &gmsg).Do()
    if (errDelete != nil) {
        logs.Error("GMAIL SERVICE ERROR:: for [", accountEmail, "] while moving message to [INBOXING] folder ", errDelete.Error())
    }
```

*Got below error :*

```
    {"level":"error","msg":"GMAIL SERVICE ERROR:: for [sample@gmail.com] while moving message to [INBOXING] folder googleapi: Error 400: Invalid label: INBOXING, invalidArgument","time":"2021-08-09 20:05:13"}
```

(**METHOD 1**) -

*[Gmail Modify API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify)*

Payload

```
    {
      "addLabelIds": [
        "INBOXING"
      ],
      "removeLabelIds": [
        "INBOX"
      ]
    }
```

*Response from Google API* -

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid label: INBOXING",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "Invalid label: INBOXING",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalidArgument"
          }
        ],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
      }
    }
```

**Observation** - *

> On modifying message with custom label's Gmail API return's 400 bad
> request, but if we request with system labels it allows us to modify
> the label.

- 

Comment: try doing it one at a time add the new one then send a request to remove the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **label name** instead of **label id**. To obtain the **label id**, you have to use the [Method: users.labels.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list)

**Response:**

[image]

Once you have the ID, you can now use it in [Method: users.messages.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify)

**Request body:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]